# Multiply matrix got it wrong don't know why, in C?

Tags: c

This code should multiply `matrix A` with `matrix B` and calculate `matrix C`.
`matA 3x2`, `matB 2x3` therefore `matC` should be `3x3.
However, when I print matC, the 3rd row contains garbage values.
I don't know where the mistake is — if I do something wrong with the pointers or maybe the calculate part is wrong.

This is what I see when printing it.

```
x x 2489458943
x x 2489587641
x x 2489745734
```

Or something like that.
I don't know why sometimes it works.
I mean it prints the correct values, but most of the time this is what I see.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 0,y = 0, z = 0;
    int i,j,k;
    int **matA;
    int **matB;
    int **matC;
    matA = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*3); // making the matrixes by malloc functions
    matB = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    matC = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
    {
        matA[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*2); // matA 3x2
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        matB[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*3); // matB 2x3
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        matC[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*3); // the calculated mat 3x3
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("please eneter line number: %i",i+1); //putting the values by scanf function in matA 
        printf(" seperated with ','\n");
        scanf("%d,%d",&x,&y);
        matA[i][0] = x;
        matA[i][1] = y;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("please eneter line number: %i",i+1);// putting the values in matB
        printf(" of the second mat seperated with ','");
        scanf("%i,%i,%i", &x, &y, &z);
        matB[i][0] = x;
        matB[i][1] = y;
        matB[i][2] = z;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) // multiple the matrixes by 3 loops
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            for(k = 0; k < 2; k++)
            {
                matC[j][i] += matA[j][k]*matB[k][i];
            }
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i ++)// just printing to check if the matrix correct
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%i ",(int**)matC[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not allocating enough space in your matrixes:

```
matA = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
matB = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
matC = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
```

You're allocating space for an array `int` but you need an array of `int *`.  Most likely, pointers are larger than integers on your system which means your arrays aren't large enough to hold what you want and you run of the end of the array.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Allocate space for arrays of `int *`.  Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc):

```
matA = malloc(sizeof(int *)*3);
matB = malloc(sizeof(int *)*2);
matC = malloc(sizeof(int *)*3);
```

You're also adding to elements of `matC` without initializing them.  You should set them to 0 before doing so:

```
        matC[j][i] = 0;
        for(k = 0; k < 2; k++)
        {
            matC[j][i] += matA[j][k]*matB[k][i];
        }
```

You also don't need a cast here:

```
printf("%i ",(int**)matC[i][j]);
```

Since each `matC[i][j]` has type `int` and you're printing an `int`.  This also invokes undefined behavior because the type of the expression doesn't match the type for the format specifier.

Comment: most systems these days are **64-bit** so **pointers** to memory addresses will be **8 bytes**.  But the `sizeof( int )` will be 4 bytes along with `sizeof( float )`.  `long int` and `double` will be 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `matC` and then use `matC +=`

The `malloc` function allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to the allocated memory. The memory is **not initialized**. Try `calloc` instead.

Also, you have wrong `int**` initialization, should allocate pointer size `sizeof(int*)`, not just `sizeof(int)`:

```
matA = (int**)calloc(3, sizeof(int*));
matB = (int**)calloc(2, sizeof(int*));
matC = (int**)calloc(3, sizeof(int*));
```